# Como hago para que este boton pase de disabled a enable

Tags: javascript

Tengo este codigo html

```
< button disabled="disabled" id="proceed" class="coss center">Proceed</button >
```

y quiero usar un código script para que en vez de decir `disable` sea `enable`, o simplemente que no aparezca el botón `disable`

Comment: ¿Dependiendo de qué pasaría a ser `disabled` o `enabled`?

Comment: solo quiero eliminar el disable del boton para que siempre este enable, si yo lo edito de manera manual por devtool y le quito la linea disable el boton automaticamente es clickeable pero si no lo hago debo resolver un catchap

Answer (score 1):

una vez que tienes definido el botón donde quieres realizar la acción, esta la añades a un evento, como vemos a continuación:

```js
function enableProceed(){
  document.getElementById("proceed").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="enableProceed()">Acción de habilitar</button>

<button disabled="disabled" id="proceed" class="coss center">Tu botón</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Te refieres a esto:

```js
const $btnProceed = document.getElementById('proceed')
$btnProceed.disabled = false
```

```html
<button disabled="disabled" id="proceed" class="coss center">Proceed</button>
```

Comment: sigue apareciendo como desactivado el boton

Comment: ese código debería estar después de tu script del captcha.